# Jquery show not working with effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm  trying to show a fixed div using the show function of jquery. The show function works, but not when I try to add an effect with jquery ui. I have both jquery and jquery ui linked in an external file via a php include. When I use the inspector in chrome, I can see the blue box of the div I'm trying to show when I click the show button, yet the page remains unchanged.

This is my html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src='js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="twitterbar" id="baremily">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/EmilyPalmaers" data-widget-id="number">Tweets by @EmilyPalmaers</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>
<div class="twitterbar" id="barcharlotte">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/CPalmaers" data-widget-id="number">Tweets by @CPalmaers</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>
```

This is my jquery:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#twitteremily").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        if( $('#baremily').is(':visible') ) {
            // it's visible, do something
            $('#baremily').hide("blind");
        }
        else {
            // it's not visible so do something else
            if ($('#barcharlotte').is(':visible'))
                $('#barcharlotte').hide("blind");

            $('#baremily').show("blind");
        }       
    });

    $("#twittercharlotte").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        if( $('#barcharlotte').is(':visible') ) {
            // it's visible, do something
            $('#barcharlotte').hide("blind");
        }
        else {
            // it's not visible so do something else
            if ($('#baremily').is(':visible'))
                $('#baremily').hide("blind");

            $('#barcharlotte').show("blind");
        }       
    });
}
);

</script>
```

and this is the css (note, the div I'm trying to show has a class and ID tag:

```
.twitterbar
{
    position: fixed;
    display: none;

    top: 35%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -10em;
    margin-left: -10em;
    z-index: 99999;


    height: 20em;
    width: 20em;

}
@media (min-width:961px) {

    .twitterbar
    {
        top:50%;
        margin-top: -16rem;
        margin-left: -16rem;
        height: 32rem;
        width: 32rem;
    }

}
```

I'm pretty much clueless at the moment, thanks in advance

Comment: you should add the markup

Comment: Hows about a jsFiddle?

Comment: You should try: `$('#barcharlotte').effect("blind");`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/a9dbeo1o/

Recheck your script references.

To make sure jQuery is ready, try:

```
if ( jQuery.isReady ) {  
    alert('jQuery is ready');
}
```

**Edit:**

Just a note: I also see you have your jquery css file inside your js folder.

**Edit 2:**

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/a9dbeo1o/2/

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the alert message :/

Comment: Would need the HTML then. The CSS is useless without it as well. There's no references to any element with the class twitterbar in your JS.

Comment: Works OK for me. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a9dbeo1o/2/
Could it be the references still? Perhaps you should try it out with some hosted libraries, just to make sure?

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to use references, weird though

Comment: Well I see you're using jquery 2.1.1, so make sure the version of your jquery-ui is compatible with it at least. I guess jquery-ui 1.11.1 would be, as it's the latest. And check if that css file is actually in the js folder. Would definitely cause issues if it's really in your css folder ;)

Comment: It is in the js folder and I'm using the latest versions for jquery and jquery ui :/